# Bent/Dented Dishwasher Door - How Repairable Is This?

Tags: dishwasher

A member of my household backed up into the dishwasher door while it was open and, in the proceeding fall, managed to put all their weight onto it, which has left the door's frame pretty seriously dented.

[image]

[image]

I confess I'm a novice to appliances, and given the time of year, I'm trying to gauge if this is fixable by a service provider, or if this is the kind of thing that results in just having to buy a replacement dishwasher.

It's a year-old Samsung, if that's helpful, so I'm hopeful if parts exist that they're available, but I was wondering what I'm looking at in terms of the extent of repairs.

Comment: The doors should be replaceable, especially for a model that is still being manufactured. However, if the chassis is damaged, that's going to be a full unit replacement. Best to call the whatever number they provided. With a dishwasher, you want it fixed and assessed properly because that door is going to leak if done incorrectly.

Comment: What is the model number?

Comment: the bent panels can probably be straightened by one skilled in the art of panel beating, but if you're going top pay someone probably to cheaper to replace with new replacement parts,

Comment: Samsung spare parts website has door inner panels for less <$200CAD in stock (in Canada) and so does PartsWarehouse.com in the US. You might get lucky. I guess it also depends on how bent the outer skin, door link and frame are.

Answer (score 2):

Repairable? And guarantee a seal? Not likely imho.

New door? Possible, but if it is still available, how long to order one? Pumps etc are “standard” repair parts and they can be difficult to get.

So, you might find out that buying a new one will be the quickest solution. Insured? A claim and subsequent premium?
Or wash up by hand until the parts arrive :)

Comment: I agree. Only being a year old would play against you here. There wouldn't be too many dead machines floating around to pick the part off (I keep our 15-year-old Kenmore dishwasher alive by raiding the shred pile at my brother-in-law's Junkyard for parts). Replacement seems like the quickest and easiest solution.

Comment: Yes, a tight seal is the biggest challenge. Further to what @DWGKNZ writes, I'd replace with the same model and keep this one for parts. Or a different model and sell/donate this one for parts.

Answer (score 1):

The parts that are easy to get are typically pumps, gaskets, filters, motors, etc. The parts that wear out in the normal use of the machine. Doors, frames, etc. are sometimes not available at all, sometimes available at ridiculous prices, and sometimes (rarely...) available at a reasonable price.

My general feeling on appliance parts is that the replacement price for parts is typically 5x - 10x the cost of the same part when included as part of the appliance. That is, a part that is a $5 part of a $500 appliance when built might sell separately for $25 - $50 as a replacement part. Which means a major part that costs $25 as part of the original appliance might sell for $125 - $250, which is likely better spent towards a new dishwasher.

However, you *may* have one other option, because the appliance is relatively new. Ordinary warranties cover factory defects and, in some cases, cover wear & tear that is beyond normal expectations (e.g., a motor that isn't defective per se but that wears out in 10 months instead of 10 years; but not a battery because battery life is extremely variable). There is no hiding that this is *not* normal wear & tear - if you made a regular warranty claim the technician would take one look and walk away. There is a *small* possibility that if you paid on a credit card that the credit card company provides an extended warranty (typically doubling the length of the original warranty) but that will also *usually* exclude accidental damage.

But there is one more option. There are "extended warranties" that include accidental damage coverage. Not all extended warranties include this coverage, so you need to read the fine print before you buy one. I am generally not in favor of extended warranties on consumer electronics, with the exception that at times I have recommended them for people sending a kid off to college because one "laptop fell out of backpack and cracked the screen" makes the extended warranty worth it.

On major appliances, this is typically based on purchase price. I bought one with my oven many years ago and it paid for itself when I needed some repairs after the regular warranty. On the other hand, I have seen people way overpay for extended warranties that are actually extremely limited service contracts, so you really need to look at the specifics: up-front cost, likelihood of using the service, cost of typical repairs if you don't have the extended warranty, exclusions, etc.

The other key thing is that *some* manufacturer extended warranty plans can be purchased *after* the initial appliance purchase. The timing varies - could be anything from "30 days" to "1 year" to "until original warranty expires + 'n' days" to "whenever". In addition, you need to determine whether pre-existing conditions (damage prior to signing the contract) are covered - sometimes they are, sometimes they are not.

If all those conditions work - still able to get an extended warranty, existing damage covered, accidental damage covered - then [Samsung Premium Care](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/samsung-care-plus/service-contract-terms-and-conditions/) is a possibility. It clearly includes accidental damage. I do not know whether you can still get it on your machine (timing from purchase date, etc.) or whether it includes damage that occurred prior to the contract.

Note that I am 100% against manipulating the system. I do **not** in any way condone ordering a contract, waiting a week and then saying "oops, this just happened the day after I signed up". That is abuse of the system and wrong. But if the contract allows for pre-existing damage then this is a great solution.